# Dynamic drupal webform

Tags: webforms

I need need next functionality from webform. For example: At start I have select field, with number values from 1 to 9.

If 2 or more are selected, then list fields for Person 1, Person 2, etc.

Participant 1
 First Name 
 Last Name 
 Email address

Participant 2
 First Name 
 Last Name 
 Email address

Participant 3
 First Name 
 Last Name 
 Email address

Do I need custom module for functionality like this one, or it is possible with existing modules?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the "[webform add more](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_addmore)" module, it's not exactly what you're looking for, but very similar...